# Update Angular5 Component from a Parameterised Route

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am having issues updating a component in Angular5 using Activated Route, my question is how do I update the view of the component after subscribing the route.params?

The variable this.type should trigger the update view on change reusing the same component, I google this but I couldn't understand how to do it.

this is my 
my.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-highlights',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})

export class HighlightsComponent implements OnInit {

public type;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  console.log(this.route.params);
  this.route.params
    .subscribe ( params => {
      this.type = params;
    }

  );
}

  ngOnInit() { 
  }
}
```

my.component.html

```
 <app-map [mode]="type"></app-map>
```

The **this.type** change should inject new value into another component triggering the update.

Comment: Can you share your routes file?

Comment: Move your logic into ngOnInIt

Comment: If I move the logic from the constructor into ngOnInit it will not update the view, what I need is to tell the subscription to update the component view after the parametrised route changes. Any other ideas?